# statsinfo extension not active after changing the configuration

Tags: linux, postgresql

I have install statinfo

```
[postgres@ 20180911 07:24:54 CentOS7604 data]$ rpm -qa | grep statsinfo
pg_statsinfo-10.0-1.pg10.rhel7.x86_64
```

and I added the following line:

```
#shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_statsinfo'
```

and I have restarted Postgres

```
[postgres@ 20180911 07:25:00 CentOS7604 data]$ ps -ef | grep postgres
postgres  1109     1  0 07:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/pgsql-10/bin/postmaster -D /var/lib/pgsql/10/data/
postgres  1148  1109  0 07:07 ?        00:00:00 postgres: logger process
postgres  1169  1109  0 07:07 ?        00:00:00 postgres: checkpointer process
postgres  1171  1109  0 07:07 ?        00:00:00 postgres: writer process
postgres  1172  1109  0 07:07 ?        00:00:00 postgres: wal writer process
postgres  1173  1109  0 07:07 ?        00:00:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process
postgres  1174  1109  0 07:07 ?        00:00:00 postgres: stats collector process
postgres  1175  1109  0 07:07 ?        00:00:00 postgres: bgworker: logical replication launcher
root      1247  1246  0 07:16 pts/0    00:00:00 su - postgres
postgres  1248  1247  0 07:16 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
postgres  1300  1248  0 07:25 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef
postgres  1301  1248  0 07:25 pts/0    00:00:00 grep postgres
[postgres@ 20180911 07:25:35 CentOS7604 data]$
```

who can tell how to solve this problem ?

best regards

Answer (score 1):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/config-setting.html#CONFIG-SETTING-CONFIGURATION-FILE) the `#` at the beginning of the line means the line is a comment and is not "active". To make that line "do something", remove the `#`

So you need change that line to:

```
shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_statsinfo'
```

note the missing `#` at the start of the line

Comment: i got another question,do you know how to  do with it ?   \n@[postgres@ 20180911 22:40:24 CentOS7604 ~]$ pg_statsinfo -r ALL -h localhost -d postgres -p 5432 -U postgres -W
Password:
ERROR: could not connect to database with "dbname=postgres host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres ": FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"@

Comment: @LTry that is totally different question and if you search for that error message you will find tons of answers.